# How can I run two domains from one dedicated server?

Tags: web-server, hosting

I have a dedicated server with a domain tied to the IP that came with the box. I got another IP assigned to the server and want to know if there's a way I can run my second domain, using that second IP, on the same server?

I know there's software like Virtualmin for hosting multiple domains on one server, but I would like to know if there's a way to do this without utilizing such software.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You don't even need two IP addresses!

Comment: Reason for downvote, from http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask "Server Fault should be your last stop in your quest for an answer, and you should tell us what you found/tried in your research and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!" You said you would like to know whether there's another way, but didn't demonstrate you tried looking for that other way.

Comment: @JayMcTee It is often said (by me in particular) the no one who needs to ever reads anything. Your quote is brilliant, I should have read it long ago. I will use it frequently #hoistbyonesownpetard.

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual host in apache for the second domain using the second IP address.

For more details refer the following link

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: And for the downvoter, man up and leave your reason.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the reason is this is a trivial question that you could easily answer on your own without asking a question on Server Fault. See JayMcTee's common on the original question.